# Determine the ideal $\langle 2i \rangle$ of the Gaussian integers $\Bbb Z[i]$. Describe the quotient $\Bbb Z[i]/\langle 2i\rangle$.

Tags: ring-theory, ideals, gaussian-integers

> Determine the ideal $\langle 2i \rangle$ of the Gaussian integers $\Bbb Z[i]$. Describe the quotient $\Bbb Z[i]/\langle 2i\rangle$.

I am having confusion with the theorem for $\langle 2i \rangle$. It's proved in my course book that for a ring $R$ and $a \in R$ the ideal $\langle a \rangle = \{ra \mid r  \in R\}$. But I've also seen that $\langle a \rangle = \{na \mid n  \in \Bbb Z\}$.

So either $$\langle 2i \rangle = \{2ri \mid r \in \Bbb Z[i]\}=\{2(a+bi)i \mid a+bi \in \Bbb Z[i]\}=\{2ai -2b \mid a+bi \in \Bbb Z[i]\} = \{2(ai-b) \mid a+bi \in \Bbb Z [i]\}$$ or $$\langle 2i \rangle = \{2ni \mid n \in \Bbb Z\}$$

which one is it here?

Answer (score 1):

You should check whatever course or book you are using for the definition, but the standard one (for a *commutative* ring $R$) is the former: $\left\langle a\right\rangle=\left\{ra\mid r\in R\right\}$. If $R=\mathbb{Z}$, this is of course equivalent to the latter.

Comment: The former definition was correct. How do I find out what $\langle 2i \rangle = \{2(ai-b) \mid a+bi \in \Bbb Z [i]\}$ should be?

Comment: Since $a+bi$ is arbitrary in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, both $a$ and $b$ can be chosen freely. Therefore, we find $\left\langle 2i\right\rangle=\left\{2ai+2b\mid a,b\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}$ which can be rewritten further as $\left\{ai+b\mid a,b\in2\mathbb{Z}\right\}$. This is probably as simplified as you can get it.